# Display Indeterminate Activity indicator while app state is restored?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, state-restoration

I have app state preservation and restoration working in my app. Restoration is quite CPU intensive and on the oldest devices supported, restoring the app state can take up to 5 seconds, so I would like to display an an activity indicator while the app state is being restored.

In the view controller being restored I have tried:

```
override public func decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    showActivityIndicator() 
    //just creates and adds UIActivityIndicatorView to view controller's view
    ...
}

override public func applicationFinishedRestoringState() {
    hideActivityIndicator()
}
```

I also tried adding it to the `UIWindow` in the App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool
    showActivityIndicator() 
}
```

But in both cases no activity indicator is displayed. I am guessing the app doesn't update its view state while being restored.

Has anyone managed to show an activity indicator while restoring the app state, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

If your restoring process executes on main thread, then there cab be reason why activity indicator not being displayed.

Try executing restoration process on background thread.

Answer (score 0):

During state restoration what you see is are not the views of your app but a snapshot image of the UI taken when the state was preserved. So any changes you make to a view during restoration, including an activity indicator, will not be seen.

> As part of the state preservation process, UIKit captures your app’s user interface and stores it in an image file. When your app is relaunched, the system displays this snapshot image in place of your app’s default launch image to preserve the notion that your app was still running.

(From: [Documentation for ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623097-ignoresnapshotonnextapplicationl))

Instead you could catch the app going into the background with the UIApplicationWillResignActive notification and make changes to the view then so that they are preserved in the snapshot that will later appear on restoration. This can be useful to do things such as disabling buttons, so that users can see that they cannot interact with the app during restoration. Then re-enable these buttons as appropriate when the app is fully active again. However if you add an activity indicator here it will not animate.

Alternatively you could use the above linked ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch() to show your launch screen during state restoration to make it clear to your users that they cannot interact - this will then fade to your restored views when restoration is complete.